# Biology In Islam - Reproduction

Tags: sharia, quran, science, miracles

In chapter 86 verse 7 & 8 it is written that

"He was created from a fluid, ejected,"

"Emerging from between the backbone and the ribs."

But as far as I know the semen is produced by the seminal vesicle and prostrate gland.
So how to justify this verse.

Comment: I don't know Arabic. But after googling, i found that the word sad-lam-ba is translated into _loins_ in 4.23 and into _backbone_ in 86.7  . ref: quranx.com/Analysis/root/sad-lam-ba

Comment: http://wpcontent.answcdn.com/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Human-body-loins-en.svg/300px-Human-body-loins-en.svg.png

Answer (score 2):

The study of Embryology will testify the correctness of the statement of Qur'an that the fluid that gushes forth from between the backbone and the ribs.

- During the development of the fetus : The gonads that is the testicles and the ovaries they originate at a site which is between the back bone ( spine ) and the ribs.
- Later in the development of the fetus the testis descends down into the scrotum out of the abdominal cavity into the scrotal sac.
- The evidence of this still : is that the blood supply to the testis comes from the Aorta ( a major blood vessel ) high up in the abdomen.
  -So even though the testis is in the scrotal sac down there blood supply comes from a artery which signifies the original position of the testis that is between the spine and ribs.

So the nourishment for the formation of semen is from the place as stated above.
So the seminal fluid coming out of the testis though apparently down in the sac , the blood supply and the origin of the testis is at the level of the last 2 ribs and the vertebral column.

Similarly the ovary descends too , during the embryonal development , but it comes to rest in the pelvis. one on each side.

So understanding Embryology will help understand the statement in Qur'an. 
By the way the testicular descent is the cause of inguinal hernias that are seen in men most often and not in women.

Comment: Please take the time to format your posts and use proper grammar; as written, this is very difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Read Embryology of the Gonads, may be you will understand then. Try to Google and see it. Testicular descent. or gonadal development . Those two searches if you read it , may be you will understand what I said. I tried to make it as simple as I can. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two people involved

> ﴾ يَخْرُجُ مِن بَيْنِ الصُّلْبِ وَالتَّرَآئِبِ ﴿

(Proceeding from between the backbone and the ribs.) meaning, the backbone (or loins) of the man and the ribs of the woman, which is referring to her chest.

http://quran.com/86/7

> backbone (or loins) of the man

AND

> ribs of the woman

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out my answer that explains these verses in classical and linguistic perspective [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51955/interpretation-of-surah-866-emerging-from-between-the-backbone-and-ribs/53662#53662), there is way more literature cited in that answer and I don't want to just copy it here. The short answer is that [Muhammad Asad](http://www.irfi.org/articles4/articles_5001_6000/muhammad%20asad%20visionary%20islamic%20scholarhtml.htm) provides a clearer translation and his commentary explains the wording,

> 86:7 "يَخْرُجُ مِن بَيْنِ الصُّلْبِ وَالتَّرَائِبِ"

The word of concern here is (tarāʾib) "ترائب". In Asad's [The Message of Quran](https://muhammadasad.com/86/7) we read,

> 86:6 "he has been created out of a seminal fluid"
>
> [86:7](https://muhammadasad.com/86/7) "issuing from between the loins [of man] and the pelvic arch [of woman]."

[Commentary by Asad](https://muhammadasad.com/86/7),

> "The plural noun tara'ib, rendered by me as "pelvic arch", has also the meaning of "ribs" or "arch of bones"; according to most of the authorities who have specialized in the etymology of rare Quranic expressions this term relates specifically to female anatomy (Taj al-'Arus)."